# Does $\mu(A) \leq \nu (A)^{1/2}$ for every open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ imply absolute continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Does $\mu(A) \leq \nu (A)^{1/2}$ for every open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ imply $\mu\ll \nu$?

This holds if $\nu$ is a Radon measure.
Suppose $\nu(B) = 0$ where $B$ is any Borel set. For any given $\epsilon >0$, there exists an open set $A\supset B$ such that $\nu(A)\leq \epsilon^2$. By our assumption, this implies
$$\mu(B) \leq \mu(A) \le\nu (A)^{1/2} \leq \epsilon. $$

Is the statement true for the general case, or are there counter examples?

If this is not true for the general case, what about we strengthen the assumption to "$\mu(A) \leq \nu (A)$ for every open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$"?

Comment: Any finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is Radon.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Could you give us a reference or a sketch for this fact? Thanks!

Comment: See Theorem 2.18 in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analaysis*, third edition.

Comment: Basically, it follows from the Riesz Representation Theorem and the fact that the Baire Algebra agrees with the Borel Algebra on any Polish space.